# Unit testing DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, delegatinghandler

How do I unit test a custom DelegatingHandler? I have the following but its complaining the innerHandler not set.

```
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://foo.com");
var handler = new FooHandler()
{
    InnerHandler = new FooHandler() 
};

var invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(handler);
var result = await invoker.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, new CancellationToken());

Assert.That(result.Headers.GetValues("some-header").First(), Is.Not.Empty, "");
```

Comment: Because your innerhandler is a foohandler whose handler is not set.

Comment: I have see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/9789952/1134076 is this the only way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set the `InnerHandler` property of the DelegatingHandler you're testing (`FooHandler`) with a dummy/fake handler (`TestHandler`) as shown in  [that linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789952/1134076) in your comment.

```
public class TestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }
}

 // in your test class method
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://example.com/");
    var handler = new FooHandler()
    {
        InnerHandler = new TestHandler()  // <-- change to use this

    };

    var invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(handler);
    var result = await invoker.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, new CancellationToken());

    Assert.That(result.Headers.GetValues("some-header").First(), Is.Not.Empty, "");
```

Unlike that post, this should be the minimum you need to set up to get your test to run.

Comment: shouldn't you add a using statement for the HttpMessageInvoker.   its Disposable

Comment: There is no need for `Task.Factory.StartNew()` (see my answer in case that's not clear).

Answer (score 7):

With `using Moq.Protected;`, you can get more control over the response outcome.

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

var innerHandlerMock = new Mock<DelegatingHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
innerHandlerMock
  .Protected()
  .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", request, ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
  .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));

var handler = new FooHandler()
{
  InnerHandler = innerHandlerMock.Object
};
var invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(handler);

// act
await invoker.SendAsync(request, default);
```

Comment: I'm getting an issue when my unit test is trying to dispose the  HttpMessageInvoker.  

 Moq.MockException : DelegatingHandler.Dispose(True) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
    All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

Comment: innerHandlerMock.Setup(x => x.Dispose());    cannot be used either

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wire `FooHandler`'s `InnerHandler` to an instance of type `HttpMessageHandler`.

You can mock using `AutoFixture` as `fixture.Create<HttpMessageHandler>()`, or you can handle-roll your own, or you can use the awesome [`MockHttpMessageHandler`](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp).

**TLDR**

There are a few small things off with the answers here so I thought of adding my answer. I recall seeing similar code as mentioned in Ray's answer, and I was thrown off by the usage of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` in there, which is totally unnecessary. `Moq.Protected` is a bit brittle for my taste; it's ok in this situation as `"SendAsync"` method won't change mostly.

The Delegating Handler follows the chain-of-responsibility pattern where one can form a chain. One doesn't get to control the last handler which will be `HttpMessageHandler`, an abstract class.

So, the simplest form of chain is,

```
HttpClient -> HttpMessageHandler impl
```

In your case, the chain is,

```
HttpMessageInvoker -> FooHandler -> HttpMessageHandler impl
```

It's convenient to use the plumbing class `HttpMessageInvoker` for testing, instead of the porcelain class `HttpClient`. In your example, `HttpMessageInvoker` ctor handles the part of wiring up its `InnerHandler` with `FooHandler`, but you need to wire up `FooHandler`'s `InnerHandler`. Note that one doesn't need to do this for `HttpClient` as there exists a helper method, `HttpClientFactory.Create()` which handles the wiring. But there isn't an `HttpMessageInvokerFactory.Create()` method. I have few tests in my repo where I have scenarios with few handlers in the chain, and I eventually ended up writing that helper method (pasted below).

Note that only `HttpMessageInvokerFactory` handles the wiring part; with others, one has to do it explicitly.

**Examples**

Putting it all together, let's say one has a simple Delegating Handler to test as `RelayHandler` which simply relays the http request,

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Simply relays request, just for fun.
    /// </summary>
    public class RelayHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        /// <inheritdoc cref="RelayHandler" />
        public RelayHandler()
        { }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

source: https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/main/src/rm.DelegatingHandlers/RelayHandler.cs

One can test it as,

```cs
        [Test]
        public async Task Relays()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

            var relayHandler = new RelayHandler();

            using var invoker = HttpMessageInvokerFactory.Create(
                fixture.Create<HttpMessageHandler>(), relayHandler);

            using var requestMessage = fixture.Create<HttpRequestMessage>();
            using var response = await invoker.SendAsync(requestMessage, CancellationToken.None);

            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
```

source: https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/main/tests/rm.DelegatingHandlersTest/RelayHandlerTests.cs

where `HttpMessageInvokerFactory` is as,

```cs
    public static class HttpMessageInvokerFactory
    {
        public static HttpMessageInvoker Create(
            params DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
        {
            return Create(null!, handlers);
        }

        public static HttpMessageInvoker Create(
            HttpMessageHandler innerHandler,
            params DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
        {
            if (handlers == null || !handlers.Any())
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handlers));
            }
            if (handlers.Any(x => x == null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handlers), "At least one of the handlers is null.");
            }

            var first = handlers[0];

            Array.Reverse(handlers);
            var current = innerHandler;
            foreach (var next in handlers)
            {
                if (current != null)
                {
                    next.InnerHandler = current;
                }
                current = next;
            }
            return new HttpMessageInvoker(first);
        }
    }
```

source: https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/main/tests/rm.DelegatingHandlersTest/misc/HttpMessageInvokerFactory.cs

The reason why `FooHandler`'s `InnerHandler` needs to be setup is because its `InnerHandler` is executed *is my guess* in your test. That said, one could have a Delegating Handler that "short-circuits" the call, and one doesn't need its `InnerHandler`.

Here is a Delegating Handler, `ThrowingHandler` that throws unconditionally.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Throws an exception.
    /// </summary>
    public class ThrowingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly Exception exception;

        /// <inheritdoc cref="ThrowingHandler" />
        public ThrowingHandler(
            Exception exception)
        {
            // funny, no?
            this.exception = exception
                ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exception));
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

source: https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/main/src/rm.DelegatingHandlers/ThrowingHandler.cs

I don't need to setup its `InnerHandler` in test as it's not used. :shrug: One could if they feel like to have a consistent test setup.

```cs
        [Test]
        public void Throws()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

            var throwingHandler = new ThrowingHandler(new TurnDownForWhatException());

            using var invoker = HttpMessageInvokerFactory.Create(
                throwingHandler);

            using var requestMessage = fixture.Create<HttpRequestMessage>();
            var ex = Assert.ThrowsAsync<TurnDownForWhatException>(async () =>
            {
                using var _ = await invoker.SendAsync(requestMessage, CancellationToken.None);
            });
        }

// TurnDownForWhatException is a custom exception
```

source: https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/main/tests/rm.DelegatingHandlersTest/ThrowingHandlerTests.cs

Note that the `TestHandler` in Ray's answer is better named as `HttpStatusOkHandler`. But, one could need a handler to spoof an Http 400 instead, and so on.

```cs
    public class HttpStatusOkHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }
    }
```

So, eventually I came up with below.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Short-circuits with a canned http response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Canned response should not be disposed if used with a retry handler
    /// as it's meant for multiuse. If so, consider using <see cref="ShortCircuitingResponseHandler"/>
    /// instead.
    /// </remarks>
    public class ShortCircuitingCannedResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly HttpResponseMessage response;

        /// <inheritdoc cref="ShortCircuitingCannedResponseHandler" />
        public ShortCircuitingCannedResponseHandler(
            HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            this.response = response
                ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(response));
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
```

source: https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/main/src/rm.DelegatingHandlers/ShortCircuitingCannedResponseHandler.cs

Answer (score 0):

Use e.g. [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.118).aspx) or [System.Web.Http.HttpServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.http.httpserver(v=vs.118).aspx) as an InnerHandler:

```
var handler = new FooHandler()
{
    InnerHandler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()
};
```

or

```
var handler = new FooHandler()
{
    InnerHandler = new System.Web.Http.HttpServer() 
};
```